# Swift JSON need to skip a group and get its child elements

Tags: json, swift

Hi I am trying to parse this JSON in swift 3 and have an object that has a group with a variable key. I am wondering how to skip this element and access its child elements to use to create JSON objects. [image: a json snippet showing code that i want to edit]

Im doing something like

```
init(JSON: [String: Any]){
    eventTime = JSON["eventTime"] as? String ?? "" 
    eventId = JSON["eventID"] as? String ?? ""
    .
    .
    .
  }
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Unrelated but are you responsible for the server side? If yes consider to declare the object for key `Statements` as array since the date is included in a property and you are strongly discouraged from using a localized date string as a dictionary key. Use a standard format like ISO8601 or `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` or UNIX timestamp.

Comment: I agree with you but unfortunately the server side design is out of my control, I would've gotten rid of the timeStamp header altogether if I was though. Thanks for your suggestion regardless.

Comment: To answer your question you simply need to enumerate the dictionary `Statements` ignoring the keys and pass the values to the `init` method. And blame the webmaster for the bad design ;-)

Comment: The format you should use to parse `eventTime` is the following: `hh:mm a zzz EEEE dd MMMM yyyy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooner or later you are going to update to Swift 4 so here's the answer (using a custom date formatter):

```
// eventTime as String (not parsed)
struct Event: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let time: String
    let headerText: String
    let zones: [String]
    let text: [String]

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey, String {
        case id = "eventId"
        case time = "eventTime"
        case headerText = "eventHeaderText"
        case zones
        case text
    }
}

// eventTime parsed as Date
struct DatedEvent: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let date: Date
    let headerText: String
    let zones: [String]
    let text: [String]

    static let formatter: DateFormatter = {
        $0.dateFormat = "hh:mm a zzz EEEE dd MMMM yyyy"
        $0.locale     = Locale(identifier:"en_US_POSIX")
        return $0
    }(DateFormatter())

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "eventId"
        case date = "eventTime"
        case headerText = "eventHeaderText"
        case zones
        case text
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)

        let rawDate = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .date)
        if let parsedDate = DatedEvent.formatter.date(from: rawDate) {
            date = parsedDate
        } else {
            let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Date is encoded in an unexpected format.")
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(context)
        }

        headerText = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .headerText)
        zones = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .zones)
        text = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .text)
    }
}

let jsonData = """
{
    "Statements" : {
        "Some Random Date" : {
            "eventTime" : "08:37 PM GMT Friday 01 September 2017",
            "eventId" : "bbb",
            "eventHeaderText" : "ccc",
            "zones" : [
                "Cali"
            ],
            "text" : [
                "hi",
                "lorem"
            ]
        }
    }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let dec = try! JSONDecoder().decode([String:[String:DatedEvent]].self, from: jsonData)
dump(dec)
```